# Selenium Webdrive (Java) - count of element

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to count the elements in selenium webdriver. I.e. I have :

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="Computer"></div>
    <div class="Computer"></div>
    <div class="Computer"></div>
</div>
```

I need to get an amount of the `div.Computer`. I've tried to use :

```
List<WebElement> v_ct = Login.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".Computer"));
System.out.println("The amount s "+v_ct.size());
```

But amount is 0 instead 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit wait before you grab the list. The elements are not properly loaded.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".Computer")));

List<WebElement> v_ct = Login.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".Computer"));
System.out.println("The amount s "+v_ct.size());
```

Comment: Glad it helped. It's common mistake I often do as well.

Answer (score 0):

var num = document.querySelectorAll('*').length  //returns the length of your node list,